# Determine the temperature required for expanding or bending?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, thermodynamics, heat-transfer, beam, metallurgy

Is there any possible way to calculate the temperature required for a metal to expand or bend with dimensions?

For example, take Mild steel with a length of 100mm, width of 150mm, and thickness of 2.5mm.

I want to know at what temperature(heating) the material starts to expand or bend.

If possible please explain in simple terms.

Comment: No temperature needed . Just enough force; lookup " cold heading".

Answer (score 0):

Any change in temperature causes a change in length or volume.

There is the Coefficient of Linear Expansion - defined for most metals.

This has been commonly used in bi-metallic strips as simple thermostats as one metal is chosen to bend more than the other for the same temperature change.

It can also be seen when bearings are heated to fit over shafts and the linear becomes radial or when bearings are put in liquid nitrogen to shrink them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, please explain, how can we measure the temperature required for expansion based on the material thickness, as far as I searched online, I was only able to see the values based on Length & Width.

Comment: It is a coefficient of **linear** expansion, so applies for length, width and thickness or x, y and z...

Comment: see https://ctherm.com/resources/newsroom/blog/coefficient-of-thermal-expansion/ and https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/linear-expansion-coefficients-d_95.html